# Use link to API in button to hit endpoint which downloads a file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, download

When hitting ${API_URL}/auditResultsExport/3 in the browser it prompts a download of a csv. I am attempting to wrap this in a button so that when the button is clicked it causes the file download.
I have tried 2 ways neither of which are working

```
  <Button onClick={this.handleDownload}>Download all results</Button>

 <Button href={`${API_URL}/Results/3`}>Download project results</Button>
```

onClick

```
  handleDownload = () => {
    console.log("clicked download")
    fetch(`${API_URL}/Results`,
     {
      method: 'GET'
    })
  }
```

Comment: you need to use an <a> tag, which can then be styled like a button. you can also use a download lib, like [mine](https://github.com/rndme/download)

Comment: Why isn't putting a href in the button good enough.? Why does it need to be wrapped in <a> as well